get access to Data of a specific column from Excel in Word using vba
I'm trying to access to excel-Data using VBA in MS Word. But I'm having trouble to get the last used rows from a specific column. I'm trying to get the Data from a specific comlumn to build a dropdown in my Word-File
I tried this:
Private Sub Test_Form()

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWorkbook As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim excelFilePath As String

    excelFilePath = "path...\File.xlsx"
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    
    Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=excelFilePath, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set xlSheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    lastRow = xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'here is where I get the problem

    xlWorkbook.Close False
    xlApp.Quit
    
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set xlWorkbook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub

In my Excel-File I have data only in the first Comlumn in the first 23 rows.
However I get lastRow=0 when I check it with MsgBox.
I also tried lastRow = xlSheet.usedRange.Rows.Count and here I actually get 23 but I can't specify the column.
Does anyone have an idea?

Add On Error Goto 0 after End If and see what Error is. You may need to add Const xlUp = -4162

Could you try:  "lastRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row"

It worked by changing
lastRow = xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

to:
lastRow = xlSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count



Another way to solve your problem could have been to take advantage
of the fact that there is a way to navigate, within a column, to the next "last used cell before an empty cell", with a shortcut.
How to use the shortcut by example :
Put some text in cells B2 to B32
Select Cell B2
Use the Windows shortcut "Ctrl + down arrow"
You see that now cell B32 is selected

This works only if there is no empty cell in the middle.

If I record a macro, using this shortcut ends up in recording this code :
Selection.End(xlDown).Select '(you need to select the top cell by code, or in Excel, 1st)
From there you should be able to find out the row of the new selection by code.

Another shortcut also exists, that would have selected the whole range with data (B2:B32) in our example (assuming again that there is no empty cell in the middle of these data and that you start with selecting B2):
Ctrl+Shift+DownArrow
It might help as well, depending on what you try to do.
But your solution is way shorter, thus better.
P.S.
Analogy : You can do the same horizontally (Ctrl+ArrowLeft shortcut)
In case of empty cells in the middle, you may repeat the Selection.End(xlDown).Select command until the resulting selected cell is very very far : you know then that you have gone too far and that you should have stopped just one occurrence before.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
